# Hiding Etag to use cache-control in jboss for static content

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss, browser-cache, cache-control

I need to disable Etag header in response so that I can set the cache-control to a large value for static content  for a web app which does not get updated say in 6 months. I am using jboss. I found a way to create filter to add the cache-control header. is there a way to not set the etag, a setting in configuration file or using filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP server actually delivering the content (and generating the ETag) is Tomcat, on top of which JBoss is built. With this, I could find the following article, which essentially says that you can't switch the ETags off, but you have to strip (filter) them from the response before it gets sent to the browser.

http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.de/2011/04/enabling-resource-caching-in-tomcat.html